# trying to solve geom_dotplot binwidth issue by generating exponential vector of values

Tags: r

What is the function for generating data for plotting an exponential curve between two points? Here's a logarithmically spaced sequence. I want to create more of a hockey stick between the start and end point, and the real end goal is the vector of values not the plot.

My use case is that I have a parameter for a plotting function that needs to ramp up slowly between the given values as I try to plot more data. This log sequence is better than a linear sequence, but it still rises too rapidly. I need to keep the values lower and then increase exponentially.

```
library(emdbook)
plot(lseq(.08, .25, 10000))
```

[image]

**Update**

Here is the full challenge for context. I'm plotting every 400th index value of `s`. The `geom_dotplot` in the final plot, `p_diff`, is wacky and needs certain `binwidth` values to correctly size the plot. I tried creating a log sequence called `binsize` and passing it to the parameter. It looks fine at low values of `s`, but increases to 0.25 too quickly (0.25 works for the final version with 10000 dots).

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(ggtext)
  library(patchwork)
  library(truncnorm)
  library(ggtext)
  library(emdbook)


# simulate hypothetical population at control group mean/sd
  set.seed(1)
  pop <- data.frame(bdi3 = rtruncnorm(10000, a=0, b=63, mean=24.5, sd=10.7),
                    id = seq(1:10000))

# create plots
  diff <- data.frame(NULL)
  binsize = lseq(0.08695510, .25, 10000)
  for (s in 1:10000) {

    set.seed(s)
    samp <- 
    pop %>%
      sample_n(332, replace = FALSE)

    ctr <- 
    samp %>%
      sample_n(166, replace = FALSE) %>%
      mutate(trt = 0)

    trt <- 
    samp %>%
      left_join(dplyr::select(ctr, id, trt), by="id") %>%
      mutate(trt = ifelse(is.na(trt), 1, trt)) %>%
      filter(trt==1)

    diff[s,1] <- s
    diff[s,2] <- (mean(trt$bdi3)-mean(ctr$bdi3))
    names(diff) <- c("id", "diff")

    dat <- 
      ctr %>%
      bind_rows(trt)


  if (s %in% seq(1, 10000, by=400)) {

  # population
    p_pop <- 
    pop %>%
      left_join(dplyr::select(dat, id, trt), by="id") %>%
      # mutate(trt = ifelse(is.na(trt), 3, trt),
      #        trt = factor(trt)) %>%
      mutate(selected = ifelse(!is.na(trt), 1, 0),
             selected = factor(selected)) %>%
      ggplot(., aes(x=bdi3, fill=selected, group=id, alpha=selected)) +
      geom_dotplot(method = 'dotdensity', binwidth = 0.25, dotsize = 1,
                   color="white", 
                   binpositions="all", stackgroups=TRUE,
                   stackdir = "up") +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey", "#e69138")) +
      scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.5, 1)) +
      scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL) +
      theme_minimal() +
      scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0, 63)) +
      xlab("\nDepression Severity as measured by BDI-II") +
      theme(legend.position = "none",
            axis.title = element_text(size=30, color = "#696865"),
            axis.text = element_text(size=24, color = "#696865"),
            plot.title = element_text(size=36, color = "#696865",
                                      face="bold"),
            plot.subtitle = element_markdown(size=27),
            plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 1.5, 0, "cm")) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = mean(pop$bdi3), linetype="dashed", 
                 color = "#696865", size=1) +
      annotate("text", x = mean(pop$bdi3)+1, y = 25, 
               label = paste0("Population mean = ", 
                              format(round(mean(pop$bdi3), 1), nsmall = 1)),
               hjust = 0, color = "#696865", size=10) +
      annotate("text", x = 0, y = 20, 
               label = paste0("Sample #", s),
               hjust = 0, color = "#e69138", size=10) +
      ggtitle("Imaginary population of 10,000 patients who meet study criteria",
              subtitle="<span style='color:#e69138'>**Orange**</span> dots represent 332 selected patients") 

    p_samp <- 
    ggplot(dat, aes(x=bdi3)) + # group=id, fill=factor(trt)
      geom_dotplot(method = 'dotdensity', binwidth = 1.2,
                   fill="#e69138", alpha=.8, color="white",
                   binpositions="all", stackgroups=TRUE,
                   stackdir = "up", stroke=1) +
      #scale_fill_manual(values=c("#f7f265", "#1f9ac9")) +
      scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL) +
      theme_minimal() +
      scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0, 63)) +
      xlab("\nDepression Severity as measured by BDI-II") +
      theme(legend.position = "none",
            axis.title = element_text(size=30, color = "#696865"),
            axis.text = element_text(size=24, color = "#696865"),
            plot.title = element_markdown(size=36, color = "#696865",
                                          face="bold"),
            plot.subtitle = element_markdown(size=27),
            plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 1.5, 0, "cm")) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = mean(dat$bdi3), linetype="dashed", 
                 color = "#696865", size=1) +
      annotate("text", x = mean(dat$bdi3)+2, y = 1, 
               label = paste0("Sample mean = ", 
                              format(round(mean(dat$bdi3), 1), nsmall = 1)),
               hjust = 0, color = "#696865", size=10) +
      annotate("text", x = 0, y = .75, 
               label = paste0("Sample #", s),
               hjust = 0, color = "#e69138", size=10) +
      ggtitle("One possible sample of these patients (N=332)",
              subtitle="Each dot is a patient sampled from the population who gets randomly assigned to a study arm") +
      annotate("text", x = 50, y = .3, 
               label = "randomize to study arms",
               size = 10, color="#696865") + 
      geom_curve(aes(x = 35, y = .6, xend = 50, yend = .35), 
                 color = "#696865", arrow = arrow(type = "open",
                                                  length = unit(0.15, "inches")), 
                 curvature = -.5, angle = 100, ncp =15) 

    p_ctr <- 
      ggplot(ctr, aes(x=bdi3)) +
      geom_dotplot(method = 'dotdensity', binwidth = 1.6,
                   color="white", fill="#f7f265", alpha=1,
                   binpositions="all", stackgroups=TRUE,
                   stackdir = "up") +
      scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL) +
      theme_minimal() +
      scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0, 63)) +
      xlab("\nDepression Severity as measured by BDI-II") +
      theme(legend.position = "none",
            axis.title = element_text(size=30, color = "#696865"),
            axis.text = element_text(size=24, color = "#696865"),
            plot.title = element_markdown(size=36, color = "#696865",
                                      face="bold"),
            plot.subtitle = element_markdown(size=27),
            plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 1.5, 0, "cm")) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = mean(pop$bdi3), linetype="dashed", 
                 color = "#696865", size=1) +
      annotate("text", x = mean(ctr$bdi3)+2, y = 1, 
               label = paste0("Control mean = ", 
                              format(round(mean(ctr$bdi3), 1), nsmall = 1)),
               hjust = 0, color = "#696865", size=10) +
      annotate("text", x = 0, y = .75, 
               label = paste0("Sample #", s),
               hjust = 0, color = "#e69138", size=10) +
      ggtitle("50% patients randomly assigned<br>to the <span style='color:#f7f265'>**control**</span> group",
              subtitle="166 of the <span style='color:#e69138'>**orange**</span> dots turn <span style='color:#f7f265'>**yellow**</span>")

    p_trt <- 
      ggplot(trt, aes(x=bdi3)) +
      geom_dotplot(method = 'dotdensity', binwidth = 1.6,
                   color="white", fill="#1f9ac9", alpha=1,
                   binpositions="all", stackgroups=TRUE,
                   stackdir = "up") +
      scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL) +
      theme_minimal() +
      scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0, 63)) +
      xlab("\nDepression Severity as measured by BDI-II") +
      theme(legend.position = "none",
            axis.title = element_text(size=30, color = "#696865"),
            axis.text = element_text(size=24, color = "#696865"),
            plot.title = element_markdown(size=36, color = "#696865",
                                      face="bold"),
            plot.subtitle = element_markdown(size=27),
            plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 1.5, 0, "cm")) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = mean(trt$bdi3), linetype="dashed", 
                 color = "#696865", size=1) +
      annotate("text", x = mean(trt$bdi3)+2, y = 1, 
               label = paste0("Treatment mean = ", 
                              format(round(trt$bdi3, 1), nsmall = 1)),
               hjust = 0, color = "#696865", size=10) +
      annotate("text", x = 0, y = .75, 
               label = paste0("Sample #", s),
               hjust = 0, color = "#e69138", size=10) +
      ggtitle("50% patients randomly assigned<br>to the <span style='color:#1f9ac9'>**treatment**</span> group",
              subtitle="166 of the <span style='color:#e69138'>**orange**</span> dots turn <span style='color:#1f9ac9'>**blue**</span>")

    p_diff <-
    diff %>%
      mutate(color=ifelse(diff < -2.3 | diff > 2.3, 1, 0)) %>%
      mutate(color=factor(color)) %>%
      ggplot(., aes(x=diff, fill=color, group=id)) +
      geom_dotplot(method = 'dotdensity', binwidth = binsize[s], dotsize = 1, 
                   color="white", 
                   binpositions="all", stackgroups=TRUE,
                   stackdir = "up") +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey", "red")) +
      scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = NULL) +
      theme_minimal() +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-5:5), limits=c(-5, 5)) +
      xlab("\nAverage Treatment Effect (Treatment Mean - Control Mean)") +
      theme(legend.position = "none",
            axis.title = element_text(size=30, color = "#696865"),
            axis.text = element_text(size=24, color = "#696865"),
            plot.title = element_text(size=36, color = "#696865",
                                      face="bold"),
            plot.subtitle = element_markdown(size=27)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype="dashed", 
                 color = "#696865", size=1) +
      annotate("text", x = 0.2, y = 25, label = "No effect",
               hjust = 0, color = "#696865", size=10) +
      ggtitle("Simulation based null distribution",
              subtitle="Plausible estimates of the treatment effect if the hypothesis of no effect is true") +
      geom_vline(xintercept = 2.3, linetype="dotted", 
                 color = "red", size=1) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = -2.3, linetype="dotted", 
                 color = "red", size=1) +
      annotate("text", x = 2.5, y = 25, label = "Reject null",
               hjust = 0, color = "red", size=10) +
      annotate("text", x = -2.5, y = 25, label = "Reject null",
               hjust = 1, color = "red", size=10) +
      annotate("text", x = -5, y = 20, 
               label = paste0("Sample #", s),
               hjust = 0, color = "#e69138", size=10) 



    p_all <- p_pop / p_samp / (p_trt + p_ctr) / p_diff +
      plot_layout(heights = c(2, 2, 1, 2))

    ggsave(paste0("animate/", s, ".png"),
           height = 40, width = 18.5, units = "in",
           dpi = 300)
  }
  }
```

The second plot to generate, `s==401`, looks fine. `binsize[401]` works for this many dots. But by the 5th plot, `s==1601`, the dots to not fit. `binsize[1601]` is too high.

I'm thinking that if I could create a better vector of values for `binsize` that rises more slowly to 0.25 this will work.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a specific programming question. Seems like a better fit for [stats.se] if you are looking for recommendations for curve shapes to match data.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a bigger ggplot issue and I've isolated that challenge to this particular issue. But I can post there if you think it's a better venue.

Comment: Or edit your question to include something related to ggplot and code so it fits here better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a maths question rather than a programming question, but there's a fairly simple programming solution.

Here's a simple function you can try. It allows you to produce a sequence of numbers between a starting and ending number just like the `lseq` function, but includes a shape parameter that controls how "exponential" the numbers appear.

```r
seq_exp <- function(start, stop, n, shape)
{
  (stop - start) * exp(seq(0, shape, length.out = n))/exp(shape) + start
}
```

So you're probably looking for something like this:

```
plot(seq_exp(0.08, 0.25, 10000, shape = 10))
```

[image]

If you set the shape parameter to 1 it is just a normal exponential curve like in `lseq`:

```r
plot(seq_exp(0.08, 0.25, 10000, shape = 1))
```

[image]

And of course you can play around with different values:

```r
plot(seq_exp(0.08, 0.25, 10000, shape = 5))
```

[image]

```r
plot(seq_exp(0.08, 0.25, 10000, shape = 30))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That's really great! This is what I was looking for.